# error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to short

Tags: java

```
public class Solution{
   public static void main(String[] args){
                 short x = 10;
                 x =  x * 5;
                 System.out.print(x);
   }
}
```

**This is my problem and below is the error I got.**

```
Solution.java:7: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to short
x =  x * 5;
^
1 error
```

**How is this conversion from int to short?**

Comment: `x * 5` results in an `int`, but you have declared `x` as `short`…

Comment: hard-coded values (5 in your example) are treated as `int` instead of `short`, so you are doing: short = short * int => short = int, which is not directly compatible. You need a type conversion

Comment: @fern17 even `short * short` results in an int.

Comment: You need to cast the whole expression: `x = (short)(x * 5)` or use the compound operator: `x *= 5;`. Either way would work.

Answer (score 3):

When you multiply two numbers together, they undergo *binary numeric promotion*, which is just a term used to mean "convert them to a common type so they can be multiplied":

- If one number is a double, the other is converted to a double
- Otherwise, if one number is a float, the other is converted to a float
- Otherwise, if one number is a long, the other is converted to a long
- Otherwise, both numbers are converted to ints.

And the result of multiplying those converted values is the type of the converted values, e.g. int times double => convert int to double => result is a double.

Notice that this doesn't go any further than int: if you multiply a byte by a byte, or a short by a byte, or a short by an int, both of those numbers are widened to int; and the result is an int.

Hence, short times int is an int.

You can either explicitly cast back to a short:

```
x = (short) (x * 5);
```

Or use compound assignment, which implicitly casts:

```
x *= 5;
```

(`a OP= B` is roughly the same as `a = (type of a) (a OP b)`)

Answer (score 2):

The 5 is explicitly an integer. Thus, by multiplying an int with a short, you will have an int.
You can try to convert with *(short)*

Comment: Doesn't actually matter that 5 is explicitly an integer: you'd have the same issue if it was `x * x`. Operands of multiplication undergo binary numeric promotion, and shorts are promoted to _at least_ an int.